# Generating Rows between two dates - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm going to split this between the problem I want to solve and how I think would be the best way to get there, but open to anything.

**Problem:**

I have leads coming in and then the next step down the funnel is trying to contact them. Both have a time stamp and can vary in length between the two drastically among leads. I want to track throughout the day how many leads are between the two steps at any given minute.

Dataset:

| ID | Created DateTime | Call DateTime | Time Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 11:58 | 12:02 | 4 |
| 124 | 11:58 | 12:00 | 2 |

**Maybe Solution:**

```py
def generate_rows(df,x):
    sample = {'Full_ID':df.iloc[x,0]}
    sample['Date'] = pd.date_range(df.iloc[x,1], freq='Min', 
                                   periods=df.iloc[x,3], name='Date')
    return pd.DataFrame(sample)

pd.concat([generate_rows(df,x) for x in range(num_rows)])
```

Giving us this output:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 11:58 |
| 123 | 11:59 |
| 123 | 12:00 |
| 123 | 12:01 |
| 124 | 11:58 |
| 124 | 11:59 |

Then I can group by `Date` and count the `ID`s to see how many leads are waiting to be called.

Comment: Can you add a reproducable data frame, for example `df.to_dict()`, and fix the code formatting in your question. You want to add every minute as a row between your existing timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

```py
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Time Gap']), ['ID', 'Created DateTime']]
out.columns = ['ID', 'Date']
out['Date'] += out.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * pd.Timedelta('1 min')

# out.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # reset index if you want
```

Output :

```py
    ID                Date
0  123 2022-09-01 11:58:00
0  123 2022-09-01 11:59:00
0  123 2022-09-01 12:00:00
0  123 2022-09-01 12:01:00
1  124 2022-09-01 11:58:00
1  124 2022-09-01 11:59:00
```